# Persist AWS Lambda state for sftp transfers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sftp

Hi I want periodically SFTP transfer a certain file to AWS S3 using Lambda. I'd like to do it via a CloudWatch event. However I want to filter only the new file uploaded.
How could I save the last read file informations?

Comment: The target is AWS S3, what is the source?

Comment: I get file from sftp server

Comment: Do you expect to have a few lambda instances running in parallel? or is limited to 1?

Comment: No it is just limited to one, receiving a CW event and transferring the file

Comment: ok. so why not just checking the file creation date and by that to decide? without additional services

Answer (score 3):

You can store the last read file information with the following services :

- dynamoDB using a table (charges apply)
- Parameter Store (in the System Manager service).

Standard parameter costs nothing and can have a size up to 4kB.

Answer (score 1):

use Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) and process it using a Lambda function the queue will save the state of the processed/unprocessed files

Comment: You mean a queue where I consume and publish a message by the same lambda? There's no expiration time?

Comment: Yes for example in the queue you will save your tasks as an object with `filename` and boolean `status` and you can update the status ( Or just remove the processed files )